# Python Pandas DataFrame matching tables or creating new ones

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

So I am reading in a bunch of .xlsx files from a directory and I want to transform them into a table.

Easy, but I am running into the problem that these excel files do not have the same headers. How can I go about creating a code that will check the excel files headers, and either append it to a table that has the same columns, or create a new one if it that format of columns does not exist.

My Code:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd
import os


def obtain_data(filename, db):
    connect = sql.connect('filepath.sqlite3')
    workbook = pd.ExcelFile('filepath' + filename)
    df = workbook.parse('Sheet1')
    new_db = db.append(df)
    print(new_db)
    new_db = new_db.rename(columns={'INDEX': 'INDX'})
    connect.close()
    return new_db


usable_files = []
for filename in os.listdir('filepath'):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(filename)
        usable_files.append(filename)
    else:
        print('no')
        print(filename)

new_db = pd.DataFrame()
for file in usable_files:
    new_db= new_db.append(obtain_data(file, new_db))
```

Note, I do not know in advanced whether the excel file will have a matching pair of columns or not. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
def obtain_data(filename, connect, data):
    workbook = pd.ExcelFile('filpath' + filename)
    df = workbook.parse('Sheet1')
    df = df.rename(columns={'INDEX': 'INDX'})
    headers = new_db.dtypes.index
    header_list = str(headers.tolist())
    header_list = ''.join(header_list)
    hash_t = str(hashlib.md5(header_list.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
    if hash_t not in hash_list:
        x = pd.DataFrame(df)
        print(x.name)
        x.name = hash_t
        print(x.name)
        hash_list.append(hash_t)
        data_frames = data.append(x)
        connect.close()
    elif hash_t in hash_list:
        print('hash is repeating. Find a way to make this code get table name.')
    print(filename + ' has been completed succesfully.')
    final_results = {'df': df, 'hash_t': hash_t}
    return final_results


usable_files = []
for filename in os.listdir('filepath'):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        usable_files.append(filename)
    else:
        print('cool')


hash_list = []
data_frames = []
new_db = pd.DataFrame()
for file in usable_files:
    connect = sql.connect('filepath_test.sqlite3')
    x = new_db.append(obtain_data(file, connect, data_frames), 
ignore_index=True)
    if x['hash_t'] not in hash_list:
        new_db = new_db.append(x['df'])
        new_db.append(x['hash_t'])
    else:
        new_db = new_db.append(x['df'])
    print(new_db)
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but have a look. If your dataframes have common column names, they're merged together resulting in a new dataframe with all the columns in both dataframes, and *any overlapping entry names are combined into a single row* (I'm not sure if this is what you want) **EDIT**: For an example of this, see how the two `Tom`s are combined in the output.

If the two dataframes don't have any columns in common, they're simply concatenated, resulting in a dataframe with the columns from both dataframes, but with no merging of overlapping entry names.

I've included a (pretty long) printout to make it clearer what's going on.

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_dataframes(merge_this_df, with_this_df):
    print "-----------------------------------------------------"
    print "Merging this:"
    print merge_this_df
    print "\nWith this:"
    print with_this_df
    print "\nResult:"

    # Check if they have common columns
    any_common_columns = any([column_name in merge_this_df.columns for column_name in with_this_df.columns])
    if any_common_columns:
        merged_df = merge_this_df.merge(with_this_df, how="outer")
        print merged_df
        return merged_df
    else:
        concatenated_df = pd.concat([merge_this_df, with_this_df])
        print concatenated_df
        return concatenated_df

# Create some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Tom", "David", "Helen"],
    "age": ["30", "40", "50"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Tom", "Juan", "Maria", "Julia"],
    "occupation": ["Plumber", "Chef", "Astronaut", "Teacher"],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "animal": ["Cat", "Platypus"],
    "food": ["Catfoot", "Platypus-food"]
})

# Collect all dummy data in a list
all_dfs = [df, df2, df3]

# Merge or concatenate all dataframes in to a single dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for dataframe in all_dfs:
    final_df = merge_dataframes(final_df, dataframe)
```

Printout:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging this:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

With this:
  age   name
0  30    Tom
1  40  David
2  50  Helen

Result:
  age   name
0  30    Tom
1  40  David
2  50  Helen
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging this:
  age   name
0  30    Tom
1  40  David
2  50  Helen

With this:
    name occupation
0    Tom    Plumber
1   Juan       Chef
2  Maria  Astronaut
3  Julia    Teacher

Result:
   age   name occupation
0   30    Tom    Plumber
1   40  David        NaN
2   50  Helen        NaN
3  NaN   Juan       Chef
4  NaN  Maria  Astronaut
5  NaN  Julia    Teacher
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging this:
   age   name occupation
0   30    Tom    Plumber
1   40  David        NaN
2   50  Helen        NaN
3  NaN   Juan       Chef
4  NaN  Maria  Astronaut
5  NaN  Julia    Teacher

With this:
     animal           food
0       Cat        Catfoot
1  Platypus  Platypus-food

Result:
   age    animal           food   name occupation
0   30       NaN            NaN    Tom    Plumber
1   40       NaN            NaN  David        NaN
2   50       NaN            NaN  Helen        NaN
3  NaN       NaN            NaN   Juan       Chef
4  NaN       NaN            NaN  Maria  Astronaut
5  NaN       NaN            NaN  Julia    Teacher
0  NaN       Cat        Catfoot    NaN        NaN
1  NaN  Platypus  Platypus-food    NaN        NaN
```

**EDIT2:** Another approach: Read sqlite database into pandas dataframe -> fix column-related stuff -> write pandas dataframe into sqlite database (overwriting the previous one):

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd
import os

def obtain_data(df_to_add):
    # Connect to database
    connect = sql.connect("my_database.sqlite")
    print "--------------------------------------"
    # Read current database into a dataframe
    try:
        current_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_database", connect)

        print "Database currently looks like:"
        print current_df
        # Now, we check if we have overlapping column names in our database and our dataframe
        if any([c in current_df.columns for c in df_to_add.columns]):
            # If we do, we can merge them
            new_df = current_df.merge(df_to_add, how="outer")
        else:
            # If there are no common columns, we just concatenate them
            new_df = pd.concat([current_df, df_to_add])
        # Now, we simply overwrite the DB with our current dataframe
        print "Adding to database"
        new_df.to_sql("my_database", connect, if_exists="replace", index=False)
        # For good measure, read database again and print it out
        database_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_database", connect)
        print "Database now looks like:"
        print database_df
        connect.close()
    except pd.io.sql.DatabaseError:
        # There's no database called my_database, so simply insert our dataframe
        print "Creating initial database named my_database"
        df_to_add.to_sql("my_database", connect, index=False)
        print "Current database:"
        print df_to_add
        # We're done here
        connect.close()
        return


# Create some dummy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Tom", "David", "Helen"],
    "age": ["30", "40", "50"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Tom", "Juan", "Maria", "Julia"],
    "occupation": ["Plumber", "Chef", "Astronaut", "Teacher"],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "animal": ["Cat", "Platypus"],
    "food": ["Catfoot", "Platypus-food"]
})

# Read all dummy data into the database
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    obtain_data(df)
```

And the output:

```
--------------------------------------
Creating initial database named my_database
Current database:
  age   name
0  30    Tom
1  40  David
2  50  Helen
--------------------------------------
Database currently looks like:
  age   name
0  30    Tom
1  40  David
2  50  Helen
Adding to database
Database now looks like:
    age   name occupation
0    30    Tom    Plumber
1    40  David       None
2    50  Helen       None
3  None   Juan       Chef
4  None  Maria  Astronaut
5  None  Julia    Teacher
--------------------------------------
Database currently looks like:
    age   name occupation
0    30    Tom    Plumber
1    40  David       None
2    50  Helen       None
3  None   Juan       Chef
4  None  Maria  Astronaut
5  None  Julia    Teacher
Adding to database
Database now looks like:
    age    animal           food   name occupation
0    30      None           None    Tom    Plumber
1    40      None           None  David       None
2    50      None           None  Helen       None
3  None      None           None   Juan       Chef
4  None      None           None  Maria  Astronaut
5  None      None           None  Julia    Teacher
6  None       Cat        Catfoot   None       None
7  None  Platypus  Platypus-food   None       None
```

Let me know if this isn't what your're looking for.

Comment: This helps my understanding but what I was hoping to achieve was if the columns aren't matching I wanted a new table to be created. Make sense?

Comment: My apologies, @Bruno, I should have taken more care reading your question. By tables, you mean a table in the sqlite database, right? What would you like to happen to the data (e.g. example with Tom)? One approach is to do the columns-related logic using Pandas (as in my answer) and just overwrite the database with that. I'll post some code you can play around with.

Comment: Thanks for your time. What I have now is I make a hash of the list of columns and save it to a list and if the hash is in the list then I want it to append to that table(which I named after the hash) but if it isn't, then I want it to create a whole new table and save the hash. I am now realizing that this may be a whole lot more complicated than what I originally thought.

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with an example of input and output? Also please include what it looks like now and what you'd want it to look like. It's easier to understand that way, I hope.

Comment: Updated. Im getting a name error right now that I havent quite looked into yet